# MySQL create table by SQL file made strange table structure

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I played with MySQL DB 5.6 as some kind of praxis. As tool for creating table I used Navicat and made table with this

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for promet
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `traffic`;
CREATE TABLE `traffic` (
`p_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`p_cbr` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`p_invnum` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`p_issued` date DEFAULT NULL,
`p_returned` date DEFAULT NULL,
`p_deadtime` smallint(4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'end date',
 PRIMARY KEY (`p_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=29 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

but when I uploaded it on hosting place by phpmyadmin I got table where each column (field) got small key on the right end? I expected that only p_id is indexed field (on the right side is grey key) but all fields also have yellow key! Under Action column for all fields is visible:
Change | Drop | Key pic |Primary| U Unique| More
Beside this, Navicat presented empty date type fields with Null contents, here, on hosting place, it's filled with 0000-00-00 and I'm not sure how to set up SQL in order to check that some particular isn't filled up, e.g. I used ISNULL on my local machine, like:

```
select * FROM traffic where p_invnum='$par1' AND ISNULL(p_returned)
```

Did I make some error or it's phpmyadmin feature? Thank you.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the structure page showing the small keys after each column? I can't reproduce this with the current release. Which phpMyAdmin version are you using? Which theme are you using (the theme is shown on the main page in a drop down menu).

Answer (score 0):

In phpmyadmin I changed theme to another, called "original", environment is now more classic, simple but structure options of mentioned table now looks different, just as I expected. Why, I don't know.
Moreover, empty date type fields, filled up with 0000-00-00 instead Null (as default values), doesn't force me to correct queries, probably MySQL accept 0000-00-00 as Null itself.

Comment: 0000-00-00 is not the same as a NULL value, but MySQL will store an invalid date as 0000-00-00. "If a date to be stored in a DATE column cannot be converted to any reasonable value, MySQL stores '0000-00-00'." The difference between your hosting platform and local environment may be the `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE` or `NO_ZERO_DATE` system variables (which can be checked and modified within phpMyAdmin from the main page under the Variables tab), or maybe the data wasn't entered in the same way on each one.